# discord.js v12 channel permissions for

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This function running in discord.js v11 does not work in discord.js v12?

```
message.channel.permissionsFor(client.user).hasPermission("EMBED_LINKS")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client.user` is [`ClientUser`](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser) type, whereas [`.permissionsFor()`](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=permissionsFor) method requires `GuildMemberResolvable` or `RoleResolvable`. The easiest way to check for your bot permissions is as follows:

```
message.channel.permissionsFor(message.guild?.me).has("EMBED_LINKS")
```

EDIT: Also, something I didn't notice at first, `hasPermission` is renamed to `has` for extended code clarity.